# SelectSingleNode return null - even with namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, namespaces, searching-xml

I know this question has been asked in a similar fashion before, but I can't seem to get this working.

I have some xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
    <Research xmlns="http://www.rixml.org/2005/3/RIXML" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" createDateTime="2011-03-29T15:41:48Z" language="eng" researchID="MusiJvs3008">
    <Product productID="MusiJvs3008">
    <StatusInfo currentStatusIndicator="Yes" statusDateTime="2011-03-29T15:41:48Z" statusType="Published" />
    <Source>
    <Organization type="SellSideFirm" primaryIndicator="Yes">
    <OrganizationID idType="Reuters">9999</OrganizationID>
```

And I'm trying to read values using xpath:

```
XPathDocument xmldoc = new XPathDocument(xmlFile); 
XPathNavigator nav = xmldoc.CreateNavigator(); 
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace(string.Empty, "http://www.rixml.org/2005/3/RIXML"); 
XPathNavigator result = nav.SelectSingleNode("/Research", nsMgr); // <-- Returns null!
```

But even a simple select of the root node returns null! I am sure I have something wrong with my namespace. Can someone please help?

Ideally I want simple lines that will let me select values from the xml file, i.e.

```
String a = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(@"/Research/Product/Content/Title").Value;
```

BTW, I have no (direct) control over the XML file content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can use an empty namespace alias and have it used automatically by the XPath expression. As soon as you use an actual alias, it should work though. This test is fine, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        string xmlFile = "test.xml";
        XPathDocument xmldoc = new XPathDocument(xmlFile); 
        XPathNavigator nav = xmldoc.CreateNavigator(); 
        XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.rixml.org/2005/3/RIXML"); 
        XPathNavigator result = nav.SelectSingleNode("/x:Research", nsMgr);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Do you *have* to use XPath and `XPathDocument`, by the way? I tend to find that LINQ to XML is a *much* more pleasant API, particularly when it comes to namespaces. If you're using .NET 3.5 and you have no particular requirement to use XPath, I'd suggest you check it out.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot for your help. I woud like to use LINQ, but I get annoyed by the impact on debugging, i.e. any change to a lamda expression means you have to restart the entire process. Thanks again! Ryan

Comment: @Ryan: Do you spend a lot of time in the debugger? I very rarely use edit and continue - I just recompile and run the unit tests again.

Comment: Always! I find stop/start very slow for development, especially if it's an ASP app.

Comment: @Ryan: So what's your unit test coverage like? Even in a web application, *most* of your significant code should be testable... and running unit tests should be quick.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried clearing out the field and then re-populate but it's making the entire node disappear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081361/why-is-there-an-error-when-clearing-out-a-field-and-adding-text. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Make the following changes

```
nsMgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.rixml.org/2005/3/RIXML"); 
XPathNavigator result = nav.SelectSingleNode("/x:Research", nsMgr);
```

Answer (score 0):

i could post, and answer my own question, for the ***native*** equivalent of this code. Instead i'll just add it as an answer to the end.

When using the native `IXMLDOMDocument` (version 6) object:

```
//Give the default namespace as alias of "x"
document.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces","xmlns:x='http://www.rixml.org/2005/3/RIXML'");

//Query for the nodes we want
document.selectSingleNode("/x:Research");
```

**Bonus Question:** Why, oh why, does no Xml Document object model query the *default* namespace when no namespace is specified... *sigh*